# Best collaborative task manager for Ubuntu and Android?

Tags: android, task-management

Right now I use Astrid as a task manager, since I can share tasks with our LoCo Team members and everything works fine. I use it with Google Chrome and Android, but I don't really like using Chrome for that.

So, does anyone know if there is an app that does it? What it need to have:

- Ability to share tasks with others;
- Android app;
- Ubuntu app.

Aside from that, I don't need much. Astrid is awesome, but without a desktop client it's a little annoying to use.

So

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hands down [Producteev](http://www.producteev.com/)

It supports the sharing your looking for, and has a windows, web, and mac, version. The web verison (in conjunction with the unity web app stuff) works exceptionally well. (in fact the windows and mac versions seem like webkit wrappers anyway)

I can accept tasks from email, im, or some other inputs (including the apps of course). It has decent tagging. There are iOS and Android apps as well.

Comment: It seems there is no Unity Web Apps integration, but there is a Chrome App, so I just installed it, made a .desktop file for Unity and there we go (:

Comment: Unity Webapps got better (if my memory serves) in 12.10. But from chrome if your running the chrome app, under tools, there is "create application shortcuts". That should launch a simple chrome window. And work quite will with unity.

Comment: Mine looks like this [Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18875117/Test%20-%20Producteev_033.png)

Comment: I'm using Unity Webapps, but it doesn't ask me to integrate with Producteev. But since there is a Chrome App, I just created a .desktop file that makes it like in your screenshot :)